# Working with IntelliJ + Spring Data + AspectJ

Tags: intellij-idea, aspectj, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-graph

I am attempting to work with a Spring Data Graph project in IntelliJ 11.1.4 Ultimate edition. The project builds fine but the editor says that the `persist()` method on my classes annotated with `@NodeEntity` can't be found. Additionally, none if the aspect enhanced methods, like persist, show up for auto-complete suggestions.

I am using the AspectJ Support plugin and I have the compiler set to AJC. Both IntelliJ and Maven can build and run the project, it appears that the editor is the only piece that has the problem.

Am I missing something obvious? Is this a limitation of IntelliJ? I thought 11.1.4 addressed this but I might be mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately AspectJ support isn't fully implemented yet - though resolve and completion should work. Could you please file a ticket in [the tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/dashboard#newissue=yes) with a small demo project attached?

Comment: Looks like in version 13.1 it is still not fully supported.